# How do I wire an MCP3004 to the pi?

Tags: gpio, mcp3008

I've ordered an MCP3004 rather than an MCP3008 from Pimoroni.
All searches for "MCP3004" give me datasheets.

All searches for "MCP3004 pi" give me guides on the MCP3008.
If I can connect ports (specified on the datasheets) identical to those of the MCP3008 to the identical pi pins, what does NC mean?
And if not, how can I wire it up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally the abbreviation N/C or NC on a chip pinout means no connection or not connected.

You wire the MCP3004 as for the MCP3008, they share a datasheet.

Just wire the corresponding pins.

Comment: Should I connect NC to Ground?

Comment: No, not connected means not connected.  Don't connect anything to those pins.